# SQL Server Long running query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Can somebody help me to understand why the query below is taking more than a minute to run?

When I comment the below line:

```
AND sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(d.name) = 1
```

the query runs in less than a second.

I'm looking for some alternatives to rewrite the query.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName ,
d.name AS DatabaseName ,
'Diff Backups Not Performed Recently' AS Finding ,
'Last differential backup: ' + COALESCE(CAST(MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(25)),'never') AS Details
FROM master.sys.databases d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b ON d.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.database_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    AND b.type = 'I'
    AND b.server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') /*Backupset ran on current server */
WHERE d.database_id <> 2 
    AND d.state NOT IN(1, 6, 10) /* Not currently offline or restoring, like log shipping databases */
    AND d.is_in_standby = 0 /* Not a log shipping target database */
    AND d.source_database_id IS NULL /* Excludes database snapshots */
    AND b.user_name = 'tsmadmin'
    AND sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(d.name) = 1
GROUP BY d.name
HAVING MAX(b.backup_finish_date) <= DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())
    OR MAX(b.backup_finish_date) IS NULL;
```

Comment: use cross apply?

Comment: UDFs are famous both for being slow to run and for interfering with the optimizer's ability to run the query.

Comment: One way is to try not apply a function to your column. What does your `sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica` do? Is it deterministic so it can be  indexed? Could you show it in your question?

Comment: what version of sql server? : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/783011/alwayson-sys-fn-hadr-backup-is-preferred-replica-runs-very-slow-on-servers-with-many-databases

Comment: sql server 2012 SP3

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case where running the function *after* the `group by` is a good idea.  Try removing the function call from the `where` and adding it to the `having` clause:

```
HAVING (MAX(b.backup_finish_date) <= DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) OR
        MAX(b.backup_finish_date) IS NULL
       ) AND
       sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(d.name) = 1
```

I'm only suggesting this because you are aggregating by `d.name`.  Normally, filtering *before* the aggregation would be better.  But, if the operation is really expensive, it might be better to filter *after* the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This turns it into a an innner join `AND b.user_name = 'tsmadmin'` so might as well use a join

`HAVING OR` may be the problem

`DISTINCT` may be a problem

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName;
SELECT d.name AS DatabaseName  
     , COALESCE(CAST(MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(25)), 'never') AS Details
FROM master.sys.databases d
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b 
  ON d.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.database_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
 AND b.type = 'I'
 AND b.server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') /*Backupset ran on current server */
 AND b.user_name = 'tsmadmin'
 AND d.database_id <> 2 
 AND d.state NOT IN(1, 6, 10)     /* Not currently offline or restoring, like log shipping databases */
 AND d.is_in_standby = 0          /* Not a log shipping target database */
 AND d.source_database_id IS NULL /* Excludes database snapshots */
 AND sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(d.name) = 1
GROUP BY d.name
HAVING isnull(MAX(b.backup_finish_date), DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())) 
       <= DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE());
```